# When is it appropriate to post one's own music/material?

Tags: discussion

I understand there is a policy that prohibits self-promotion and product placement. But, I'm wondering when it is ok to post one's own material on this SE?

I assume it is acceptable in instances where a question is asked regarding one's own performance and/or application of theory, etc. Also, in any case where an answer can be given using an example from one's own repertoire...

Is that correct? And, are there other instances that this can happen?

Comment: Related: general guideline from SE help center on [how to not be a spammer](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). It's not really prohibited, though.

Answer (score 6):

I imagine it's okay to do this as long as you're upfront about it. Some people get in trouble for just trying to *sell* their products/music in "answers", but if there's a legitimate reason to use your own material, I think it's probably okay. If you're using your own work as an example, do it because it's a good example - not because you just want to.

One reason I try to stay away from that, though, is that I think there are generally better pieces of music to use as examples, and people will know them better than my own work. Plus, sometimes I make mistakes, and I'd rather analyse someone else's work than my own.

That, and I'm a fairly anonymous user, too.

Answer (score 3):

It would be applicable as long as it was still a valid in scope question here, and that you aren't using this site as a self promotion tool (which some have tried in the past)

By in scope, I mean don't ask "What do you think of this piece?" but instead your music piece is used to support a question, you link to the relevant point in the song etc.

If you look at questions which do include audio or video you will see what works - it's usually around specific points, not whole pieces, so consider just including the relevant sample.